# Apply protection to multiple sheets in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, access-control

Ive got a Google Spreadsheet with 50+ data tabs, and 5 Summary tabs at the end.

The 50+ data tabs all have the same column headers.

I want to apply protection to the all these data "data tabs" to stop some people who have edit rights on the spreadsheet from editing the data. Eg. "John" who has edit rights on the spreadsheet would not be able to edit the data in the data tabs, column A:Z, except column E.

In the past Ive done this manually by applying protection to each tab, but its really fiddly, its also really fiddly when i need to edit the protection rules, is there a more automated way i could manage this ?

Perhaps by setting the protection rules as a template then applying that template to the tabs i need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built-in feature to protect or edit the protection of several sheets at once but Google Apps Script could be used to automated this task or an add-on created by yourself or by someone else.

Reference

- [Use Add-ons & Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
- [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Related

- [Script to add protection and remove the user running it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95751/88163)