# Option to protect all sheets in a Google Sheets spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Underneath "Tools" in the menu bar, there is the "Protect Sheet" option, which pops this sidebar on the right-hand side of the screen:

[image: Protected sheets & ranges]

Which works well, however there doesn't seem to be an option to protect all sheets in the spreadsheet.

After googling this, I found only one relevant thread:

[Protect All Sheets by Default](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/5387589?hl=en)

Which is just a collection of complaints of various users who want the same feature.

Is there an option to protect all sheets in a Google Sheets spreadsheet?

Comment: What is the question? Please bear in mind that feature requests should be sent directly to Google.

Comment: I updated the question body.

Comment: Short answer There is no built-in function for that. You could use Google Apps Script to protect all the sheets automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As per Rubén's comment and [this other thread on the topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95751/script-to-add-protection-and-remove-the-user-running-it), the answer is no, you cannot protect all sheets in a spreadsheet from the GUI. You can, however, achieve the same effect if you know how to use Apps Scripts:

```
function protectAllSheets() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();

  for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i += 1) {
    const sheet = sheets[i];
    let protection = sheet.protect();
    protection.setWarningOnly(true);
  }
}
```

Note that this will let any user edit the spreadsheet, but show a warning before the change is committed.